# Error 'Call to a member function format'

Tags: php, date, formato, booleano

> Call to a member function format() on boolean in

```
$fDevolucion = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $Fechadevolucion);
($prestamos = $objprestamo->addprestamo($fDevolucion->format('d-m-Y'),$cliente,$libro,$observacion)){ <-- ERROR EN ESTA LINEA
```

Answer (score 2):

El error se debe a que la variable `$fDevolucion` es un booleano, puntualmente igual `false`.
Esto solo puede suceder cuando [`DateTime::createFromFormat` falla](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-returnvalues).

### Solución:

Validar que `$Fechadevolucion` cumpla con el formato `d-m-Y`, es decir, que `$fDevolucion` sea distinto de `false`.

Ejemplo:

```
$fDevolucion = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $Fechadevolucion);
if ($fDevolucion !== false) {

  $prestamos = $objprestamo->addprestamo($fDevolucion->format('d-m-Y'),$cliente,$libro,$observacion);
  if ($prestamos) {
     ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu línea 1 de código `$fDevolucion = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $Fechadevolucion);` es muy probable que `'d-m-Y'` no sea el formato correcto para procesar `$Fechadevolucion` y al final, `$fDevolucion` está retornando `false`.

Intenta hacer un `echo` a `$Fechadevolucion` para asegurarte que el formato correcto sí es `'d-m-Y'`.